# make server auto-append @domain.com to ftp account

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ftp, mediatemple

I have a client who, printed 10,000 advertisements with a specific password for an FTP account written on it lets say: horses1, for many reasons I have had to migrate her over to a new host, she chose mediaTemple, and bought an account.

The Login is now horses1@HER-DOMAIN.com, which is a problem, becuase of all her print ads.

I'm thinking this can be fixed with mod_rewrite and htaccess, but I'm pretty sure apache2 and ftp are different programs... I'm really screwed if I cant fix this....

EDIT:
is there a way to create an FTP user alias?

Comment: advertising ftp account information in print ads? That's a first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache is just a HTTP server. But maybe [mod_ftp](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_ftp/mod/mod_ftp.html) and its [`StripHostname` option](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_ftp/mod/mod_ftp.html#ftpoptions) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is an HTTP server (which, due to being magic, can be made to act like pretty much any kind of TCP/IP server you like, but almost never is) so won't be responsible for the FTP.

The FTP will almost certainly be supplied by a different server, and you'll need to find out what that is and what level of configuration control you have on it before you can proceed any further.

Answer (score 0):

FTP sites that need @domain are almost always shared hosts.

You will not be able to make configuration changes to make it work without.